# AWS SES: Adding a topic to an existing contact list (NotFoundException - List doesn't contain Topic)

Tags: amazon-ses

I have a SES (AWS Simple Email Service) contact list where each contact has a list of topic preferences, e.g.

```json
// aws sesv2 get-contact-list --contact-list-name my_contact_list

{
  "ContactListName": "my_contact_list",
  "Topics": [
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_1",
      "DisplayName": "...",
      "Description": "...",
      "DefaultSubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    },
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_2",
      "DisplayName": "...",
      "Description": "...",
      "DefaultSubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    }
  ],
  "CreatedTimestamp": "2022-04-12T11:40:48.061000+01:00",
  "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2022-05-12T11:01:13.596000+01:00",
  "Tags": []
}
```

And when I list the contacts:

```json
// aws sesv2 list-contacts --contact-list-name my_contact_list

{
  "EmailAddress": "name.surname@example.com",
  "TopicPreferences": [
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_1",
      "SubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    }
  ],
  "TopicDefaultPreferences": [
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_2",
      "SubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    }
  ],
  "UnsubscribeAll": false,
  "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2022-05-16T09:14:16.483000+01:00"
}
```

I would now need to add a new topic to the contact list. However, I can't find any way to update the list, or the existing contacts in that list.

When I try to send an email to that list with a new topic, I get this error:

```
"An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the SendEmail operation: List: my_contact_list doesn't contain Topic: transactional_emails_3
```

What I would end up with is a situation where the contact list contains the new topic (transactional_emails_3) and each user in that list is subscribed to it:

```json
// aws sesv2 get-contact-list --contact-list-name my_contact_list

{
  "ContactListName": "my_contact_list",
  "Topics": [
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_1",
      "DisplayName": "...",
      "Description": "...",
      "DefaultSubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    },
    {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_2",
      "DisplayName": "...",
      "Description": "...",
      "DefaultSubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    },
   {
      "TopicName": "transactional_emails_3",
      "DisplayName": "...",
      "Description": "...",
      "DefaultSubscriptionStatus": "OPT_IN"
    }
  ],
  "CreatedTimestamp": "2022-04-12T11:40:48.061000+01:00",
  "LastUpdatedTimestamp": "2022-05-12T11:01:13.596000+01:00",
  "Tags": []
}
```

Can it be done using the AWS SDK (SESv2 API)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the UpdateContactListCommand. You have to be super careful though as according to the docs:

'Updates contact list metadata. This operation does a complete replacement.'

The best way is to first get your contact list using the GetContactList command, extract the topics, then add your new topic to the array send it. This should ensure that you original topics are not changed. This should look something like the following:

```js
import {
    GetContactListCommand,
    UpdateContactListCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-sesv2";
import { SESv2Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-sesv2";

const client = new SESv2Client({ region: "us-east-1" });
const ContactListName = "contact-list";
const getListCommand = new GetContactListCommand({ ContactListName });
const { Topics } = await client.send(getListCommand);
Topics.push({
    TopicName: "en-weekly-newsletter",
    DisplayName: "Weekly Newsletter",
    Description:
        "A round up of work and discoveries from the last seven days.",
    DefaultSubscriptionStatus: "OPT_IN",
})
const updateListCommand = new UpdateContactListCommand({ ContactListName, Topics });
const res = await client.send(updateListCommand);
```

Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sesv2/classes/updatecontactlistcommand.html